# Oracle converting to Eastern Time Zone

Tags: oracle

I am running an API call that runs the following Oracle code for DAO, and suppose to bring back the latest banner scheduled by DT/TM.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM BANNER_MSGS WHERE from_tz(cast(SYSDATE as timestamp), 'GMT') at time zone 'US/Eastern' BETWEEN SCHEDULE_FROM AND SCHEDULE_TO  order by Banner_ID DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY";
```

This works all day on my localhost but when moved to DEV server it will simply not work.  Any Oracle gurus have some wisdom for the `SQL` syntax.

Comment: Can you define "not work"?  And provide a reproducible test case?  What data type is `schedule_from` and `schedule_to`?  I'd hope that you could just check whether `systimestamp` is between the two values but it depends on things like data types.

Comment: SCHEDULE_FROM and SCHEDULE_TO are datatype = TIMESTAMP(6).  Example - SECHEDULE_FROM = 18-FEB-21 10.43.00.000000000 PM and SECHEDULE_TO = 18-FEB-21 10.46.00.000000000 PM.  As you can see I was testing between a small time frame, which again works locally, but doe not work on deployed code.  I am perplexed.

Comment: Are you local DB and the dev DB in the same time zone? Maybe your is UTC/GMT but dev is already EST, in which case you're incorrectly adjusting the time? ANd what are the two session time zones?

Comment: The LOCAL and DEV were pointing to the same DEV Oracle DB, the problem was my Webserver TomCat was running in EST and the setting on upper environments are on UTC.  Who knew.  Thank you so much for the help.